# Computing time complexity for two code blocks

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

#### Code 1

What is the time complexity `T(n)` of the below code, if we assume `n` is divisible by 4? Can somebody please explain this to me?

```
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<=n;)
  {
    std::cout<<i<<" "<<j<<"\n";
    j=j+(n/4);
  }
}
```

#### Code 2

What is the time complexity `T(n)` of the nested loops below? Assume that `n` is a power of 2. That is, `n = 2^k` for some positive integer `k`.

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
  j = n;
  while(j>=1)
  {
    <body of the while loop> //Needs θ(1)
    j=⌊j/2⌋; // ⌊⌋=>Floor function
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice and simple guide. https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/. A more lengthy guide: https://programming.guide/time-complexity-explained.html

Comment: Thank you for the guide. I will check it out.

Comment: And this is also awesome: https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/. It could help you understanding the theory

Comment: A quick test is to find the loop that does the wok and add a counter. do a bunch of runs, then plot count vs `n` and see what sort of curve you get.

Answer (score 2):

Code 1 is linear. `j += n / 4` means that the inner loop runs a constant number of times (5) for any value of `n`, and 5n reduces to O(n).

Code 2 is O(n log(n)). The outer loop runs `n` times and the inner loop runs `log2(n)` times as it repeatedly divides the input in half.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you explain more? Thank you

Comment: I can be wrong... But the code also runs for n times for the outer loop right? So n * (n/4) will be n²?

Comment: No, `n / 4` is constant. The intuition is that for `n=40`, how many iterations do you get? 4. For `n=4000000`, how many iterations do you get? Still 4. I'm not sure how else to explain: the outer loops are obviously O(n) and the inner loops are as I described them in the post. Multiply the inner loop and outer loop times together and remove any constants.

Comment: @GoldenArcher The inner loop has 5 iterations for each value of `i`, not `n/4` iterations. (`j` will assume the values `0`, `n/4`, `n/2`, `n*3/4`, and `n`, when `n` is divisible by 4.) So overall you are looking at n*constant, or θ(n).

Comment: Good call, JaMiT, 5 iterations but it amounts to the same thing from a complexity standpoint.

Comment: @ggorlen So, for code 1, It's gonna be O(n). Right?

Comment: Yep. The outer loop runs to `n` and then the inner loop has 5 constant time ops no matter what `n` is.